# Userinput variable not updating

Tags: c++, user-input

I am running into an issue with my code. Up top I declared and initialized a variable named "userRadius" later I request the user to input a radius so that it will update the variable and display the "diameter" variable. But when I run the program the user input does not affect the diameter variable and it outputs zero, however if I hard code the the math into the output it works just fine. Any ideas?

```
int option{};
double userRadius{};
const double pi = 3.14159;

//display
cout << "Please enter 1 for Diameter:\nPlease enter 2 for Circumference:\nPlease enter 3 for Area:\nPlease enter -1 to quit:\n";
cin >> option;
//math
//double diameter = userRadius * 2;
const double circumference = 2 * pi * userRadius;
const double area = userRadius * userRadius * pi;
```

```
else if (option == 1) {
    //output
    cout << "Please enter radius: ";
    cin >> userRadius;
    //cout << userRadius;
    out << "The diameter is: " << userRadius * 2;//OUTPUT
}
```

I created a variable that would be updated by the user input and display the the userinput multiplied by 2 and expected a number which would be the diameter.

Comment: The order that you do things matters in C++ (and most languages). If you want to calculate a diameter from a radius and you want to input a radius, you have to input the radius first, and then do the calculation, not the other way around.

Comment: @john Thank you I just changed it and now my problem is solved. I will make sure I keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is not Excel.  Variables are evaluated at the point they are used.  Updating the value of a variable will not update any other variables that already used the old value of the updated variable.

To do what you are attempting, you need to *recalculate* your `circumference` and `area` variables *after* updating `userRadius`, eg:

```
int option{};
double userRadius{};
const double pi = 3.14159;

//display
cout << "Please enter 1 for Diameter:\nPlease enter 2 for Circumference:\nPlease enter 3 for Area:\nPlease enter -1 to quit:\n";
cin >> option;

//math
//NOT CONST HERE!!!
double diameter{};
double circumference{};
double area{};

...

else if (option == 1) {
    //output
    cout << "Please enter radius: ";
    cin >> userRadius;
    //cout << userRadius;

    // RECALC HERE!!!
    diameter = userRadius * 2;
    circumference = 2 * pi * userRadius;
    area = userRadius * userRadius * pi;

    out << "The diameter is: " << diameter;//OUTPUT
}
```

Comment: Thank you I did something very similar and the code worked as intended.